# What are the purpose of api specific typedefs such as GLsizei GLint GLvoid?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, typedef

What are the purpose of api specific typedefs such as GLsizei GLint GLvoid?

I see this everywhere in c and c++ code. Basic types are often typdefed with the libraries prefix/suffix. What's the reasoning behind this? Is this good practice? Should my programs be doing something similar themselves?

At first glance it seems to make the code a little bit less readable. You have to take an instant to translate GLint into int in your head, and that's an easy example.

Something like UINT makes more since to me, at least this is shortening unsigned int into four lettters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about shortening the names, but about portability. Different platforms will need to typedef those things differently.

In Std-C, `long` may be 32 or 64 bits, depending on your compiler/target, so it can't be safely assumed to be a certain size. A library author will thus typedef his own type, guaranteeing a certain size, with the knowledge of the target platform.

E.g.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
typedef __int64 INT64;  // long will not be 64 bit on Windows/VC.
#elif __GNU_C__
typedef long INT64;  // gcc typically uses 64 bit longs.
#elif // ... other platforms ...
...
#endif
```

And if compilers change type properties in future versions, the types can be edited in one place.

In the past you also had a typical case where `int` might be 16 or 32 bits in size, so you couldn't simply use the raw `int` type in code where you needed a `DWORD`-sized argument.

Hence why you have things like `LPARAM` and `WPARAM`.

It's also used as a form of abstraction. Which is why you see typedefs like

```
typedef int Handle;
```

Because while it's an `int` now, the library author reserves the ability to change it later down the track to anything else, say a `void *`, or any other type they deem necessary.

But the client code doesn't need to know it's an `int` specifically, since that's just what it currently happens to be. All the client needs to know is to pass it along to functions accepting a `Handle` type.

Typedefs also allow configuration at compile time. E.g. some libraries may have a `Real` type for real numbers. It could be defined in a way such as

```
#ifdef USE_DOUBLE_PREC
typedef double Real;
#else
typedef float Real;
#endif
```

And the user of the library can optionally set `/DUSE_DOUBLE_PREC` when compiling to get double precision float support, but the important thing is that no library code needs to change for this to work, since it's been abstracted.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, when a library defines basic types with no guaranteed properties beyond similarly named types in the standard (think `INT`, `GLint`, `gint`, `LPSTR`, `u32`, `u_int`, etc.), the purpose is either:

1. To "brand" your code with lots of tight dependency to the library so it's a pain to reuse your code without the library, or
2. Ignorance that the C standard provides appropriate types for the library's needs.

Based on one of my favorite principles "Never attribute to malice what can adequately be explained by stupidity", you might go with #2, but it's really up to you.

Personally whenever coding to such an API, I throw out the library-specific types and use the correct natural types (`int`, `char *`, `uint32_t`, etc.) in their place. Then it's easy to adapt my code to use without the library should I ever need to, and the code is more readable to people not familiar with the library.

Comment: Slow down there with "C standard", OpenGL is not just for C and has nothing to do with C (or any other programming language). :) It's not a "library", it's an API.

Comment: There's no such thing as a language-independent API. Surely you could attempt to make similar-looking versions of the API for a number of languages, with mixed success. (Good luck making the OpenGL API look the same in Brainf*ck..) When instantiating the API in a particular language, you need to follow the conventions of that language, especially in terms of types. Many languages don't even have types, and trying to impose some ridiculous idea of `GLint` on them rather than using their native way of representing integers would have users of the language up in arms. C deserves the same respect.

Comment: @Kos: It's a standard, with a specification. The specification is written in a language-agnostic way.
@R: The platform OpenGL headers are written with C89 in mind. C89 did not have typedefs for integral types with exact sizes, like int32_t, so they had to define their own. Also, your 1.) is wrong. Why would anyone do that on purpose? Usually whenever you see something weird, you can often blame it on *legacy code*, not malice or stupidity.

Comment: @R. - "imposing the ridiculous idea of `GLint` is actually what you have to do if you want to impose the similarily ridiculous idea of an "external library API". And the whole point of having `GLint` defined is that you don't have to actually consider whether a regular `int` is 16 or 32 or  64 bytes on platform XYZ, which allows you to code in a portable way.

Comment: @Kos: If the point of `GLint` is to always be 32 bits, they chose a really bad name for it. Reading it, I would expect it (like Windows' `INT` and glib's `gint`) to be a platform-specific integer type of natural size, probably always defined as `int`. @Mads: If you read my answer you'd see that I suggested 2 is a better interpretation right after offering them both. However in some cases (glib for sure), it's really 1.

Comment: The meaning of GL_INT is to be *"a value of the same type as the INT mentioned in GL specs".*

Comment: @Kos: *Type* is a language-specific construct. A proper attempt to be language-agnostic would say something like "an integer value in the range -2^31 to 2^31-1", and then the language-specific binding would choose an appropriate type (such as `int32_t`) if the concept of types is relevant to the language. Naturally in script-language bindings, they'd all just be strings. :-p

Comment: @R - And that's how it is! :) See 2.1 and 2.4 in [OpenGL specs](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.pdf).

Comment: Then they should be using `int32_t` in C.

Answer (score 1):

It gives the ability to change the typedef in one place rather than searching-and-replacing all over the codebase if the need somehow arose to change the underlying type. However, I also find it more "noise" than anything and have rarely seen it ever needed in a real-life scenario.

The only example I've seen a decent use is for floats if you happen to be working in games and might have need to have your game ported from/to the Nintendo DS since the DS natively works with fixed-point numbers. In that case, you have a special typedef for the float so that it really is typedef'ed to a float on most platforms and to a special fixed-point class on the DS.

Comment: Fixed-point and float have so little in common that any code that works with fixed-point probably wants and should be using fixed-point everywhere...

Comment: You'd be surprised how easy it is to abstract that away in a class. A company I did contract work for had such an engine that had BLAH_FLOAT (where "BLAH" was their company initials) everywhere so that DS and non-DS versions of their code peacefully co-existed.

Comment: I didn't mean in implementation but in semantics. For instance if your values are coordinates they should be either fixed point or floating point with a **huge** bias added. Otherwise precision varies with position, being much higher at the origin than far away from it, which means behavior is not translation-invariant.